# css dynamic class based on parent class

Tags: css, typeahead.js

I'm using Twitter's `typeahead.js` to auto-fill two different input boxes on my page as the user enters information into them.

The way the library works is that it adds a `<div>` element underneath the input box with a class called `tt-menu`.

My first input box has a width of 850px, so I added a class in my CSS as follows, which overwrites typeahead.js's default width of "auto":

```
.tt-menu {
 width: 850px;
}
```

This forces the typeahead dropdown on the input box to be the same with as the input box itself, and it works fine.

My issue is that my second input box is only 650px - so the typeahead dropdown is 200px larger than the input box.

As each of my inputs has its own class, I'm wondering if there's a way for me to change the `tt-menu` class depending on the input box that it's under, something like:

```
.inputBoxA tt-menu {
  width: 850px;
}

.inputBoxB tt-menu {
  width: 650px;
}
```

But this solution does not work.

## Edit

In the event the accepted answer does not work for someone who happens upon this thread

```
.inputBoxA > tt-menu
```

what worked for me ultimately was

```
.inputBoxA .tt-menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different CSS selector to better define that it is a **child of the menu**.

You can do so by using `>` in your CSS selector, something along the lines of:

```
.inputBoxA > tt-menu { width:850px; }
```

This selects all tt-menus' under the .inputBoxA parent.

If this specific example doesn't work or you wish to read more about this concept look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: @DavidThomas Grammatical error from a student, thank you for pointing that out and I'll be sure to adjust it in the future. :-)

Comment: No worries, I've taken the liberty of editing the typo now, though, simply because, that way, you're less likely to receive down-votes because of either the acknowledged error being left in place, or because the `<` character isn't a valid CSS combinator (though your code example should probably have protected you from that kind of censure). :)